# Set global tint in Cocoa applications

Tags: cocoa, colors, macos-big-sur, tint

I noticed that many apps uses a custom global tint color like Pages (Yellow) or Music (Red). `NSAlert` default buttons respect this tint, as `NSOpenPanel` and others do (for example drop-down arrow as show in picture).

I alos noticed that `NSAlert` brings a delete button that shows text in red. Do you know how to get it to appear?

Thanks

How could I specify a specific global color. I create UI using code and not Storyboard.

[image: Pages Yellow tint example]

[image: Music Red tint example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching in Apple's app folders, such as Pages, I found what we need to do to change the app's overall tint.

1. Create a color object in the Asset;
2. In the `info.plist` add the key `NSAccentColorName` that is a string assigned to the color name created at step 1;

This colors `NSAlert` default buttons and all control's accent elements.